# Where is std::thread::join implemented in libcxx

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I wonder where `std::thread::join` is implemented in *libcxx*. While it is declared in `<thread>` header, there seems to be no definition. I even looked at *libcxxabi*, but could not find it there either.

So could someone point out, where it is implemented?

Comment: Not all functions are defined in the headers, they might be implemented in the link-time library.

Comment: src/thread.cpp at the very beginning.

Comment: @bamboon, thanks. Was expecting it to be in headers.

Comment: @LCIDFire Why's that?

Comment: @bamboon: That should be an _answer_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit probably because I was dead tired ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's in [src/thread.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/thread.cpp), near the top:

```
void
thread::join()
{
    int ec = pthread_join(__t_, 0);
#ifndef _LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS
    if (ec)
        throw system_error(error_code(ec, system_category()), "thread::join failed");
#else
    (void)ec;
#endif  // _LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS
    __t_ = 0;
}
```